# Jasmine: Create spy on window objects that don't exist

Tags: angularjs, cordova, jasmine, spy

I'm building a cordova / phonegap app along with AngularJS. In my app, I'm using some native plugins from cordova, like the geolocation plugin.

During my tests, this plugins aren't available (because phonegap isn't present), `$window.plugins` returns `undefined` in my tests. And of course, `$window.plugins.anotherPlugin` also fails.

Therefore, I have to mock out this parts for my tests. Currently, I'm doing it this way

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    $window.plugins = {
      anotherPlugin: {
        foo: function() {}
      }
    };
  });
```

But what if in the future, another library uses the `$window.plugins` namespace, and I'm overwriting it in my tests? This would break other tests. With the way above, I would have to do some cleanup after my tests, to ensure that the old values of `$window.plugins` are set back. I think, this way isn't very clean, and I wonder if there is a better way to do this with jasmine.

So my question is: **How can I spy on `$window.plugins.anotherPlugin` by creating dummy functions with jasmine, without affecting other tests, when `$window.plugins` doesn't exist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the module of the part you want to test and generate a mock module, which provides the spies.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('ModuleUnderTest', function($provide) {
        var windowMock = {
            plugins: {
                anotherPlugin: jasmine.createSpyObj('anotherPlugin', ['foo', 'bar'])
            }
        };

        // substitute all dependencies with mocks
        $provide.value('$window', windowMock);
    });
});
```

Beware, I have not tested the code, but you should get the gist.

Comment: That looks good. But this causes another problem: I have a library (angular moment.js) that uses `$window.moment.lang(lang);`. When using  the approach above, it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined`. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Can't you just mock that function as well? If you really need it, you may use the inject function before the module initialization, grab the moment object and put it on your mock object. e.g. var moment; inject(function($window) { moment = $window.moment; }); module(..., function ($provide) { windowMock.moment = moment; ... });